# Add Object Root to JSON

Tags: json, grails, marshalling

I'm looking for a way to add object roots to my JSON in grails (2.4.5). Generally, Grails renders JSON list of objects like so:

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Catan","description":"Catan"}]
```

But I need it to look like:

```
{"games": [{"id":1,"title":"Catan","description":"Catan"}]}
```

Ideally I'd like to adjust the custom marshaller I've created to do this, but I'm not sure how to go about it:

```
class GameMarshaller {
    void register() {
      JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Game) { Game node ->
        return [
          id            : node.id,
          title         : node.title,
          description : node.description
        ]
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30273192/grails-domain-class-json/30273552?noredirect=1#comment48646217_30273552), it just about making the root element to be a **map** and adding the **list** into it with key `games`, then conver it to a **JSON**.

---

So this should work for your case:

```
class GameMarshaller {

    void register() {

      def games = Game.list().collect{ node ->
         [
          id            : node.id,
          title         : node.title,
          description : node.description
        ]
          }

      def result = ([games: games] as JSON)      

   }

}
```

Comment: That's not what I want, because I do NOT want the marshaller pulling the data from the database. The data will have already been fetched at this point. Doing it twice is a bad idea.

Comment: @user903772 this is just an example to show how to add root element into a JSON. But yes using pagination could be a solution.

Comment: @Gregg, I am not sure if list() method uses hibernate cache or directly hits database,  but it is better if you post this requirement as part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Can this help?

```
def o = new JSONObject()
def arr = new JSONArray()
def g = new JSONObject()

games.each{
    g.put("id",it.id)
    ...
    arr.add(g)
}
o.put("games",arr)
respond o
```