# Grails Domain class JSON

Tags: json, grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I have this controller:

```
respond :Alert.list()
```

It gives:

```
[{id: ..}, {id: ..}]
```

What I want:

```
{"alerts":[{"id":...}. {id:..}]}
```

How do I let the respond make into the format I want? I don't want to have a custom JSON marshaller as my dataset is big.

What will be the outcome if I do the following than having a custom marshaller?

```
def o = new JSONObject()
def arr = new JSONArray()
def a = new JSONObject()

alerts.each{
    a.put("id",it.id)
    ...
    arr.add(a)
}
o.put("alerts",arr)
respond o
```

Comment: It seems that you forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
  //do your filtering here to get alertList


respond: [alerts: alertList]
```

Comment: can not. this is a map in a index operation

Comment: what do you mean by that? I did not get you

Comment: IF I do your way, I cant exclude properties

Comment: well I did not see any filtering on ur question, updated the answer.

Comment: is there an easy way to exclude properties?

Comment: You need to do it yourself. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271068/add-object-root-to-json/30273733#30273733 it is taking part of the domain object fields to build its JSON.